# Postman HeaderList remote function not working

Tags: postman, http-headers, postman-pre-request-script, authorization-header

I have this Pre-request Script:

```
pm.request.headers.remove("Authorization");
pm.request.removeHeader("Authorization");
```

But my request still comes with an Authorization header. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something stupid here. Any ideas?

Comment: How is the authorization being added?  Authorization can be set with the authorization helpers and so they don't really exist on the request until its run.  Try console logging the headers in your pre-request script.  You'll find it only has ones you have specifically added.  Any auto-generated ones including the authorization header won't exist at this point.  They only get added just before the request is sent.  You may need to stop using the authorization helper, and set the auth header within the pre-request script instead.

Comment: You are right indeed. I'll have to handle it entirely from the pre-request scripts then! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As [@mikee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22769054/mikee) suggested I ended up making a collection wise pre-request script to handle the `Authorization` header. Unfortunately it looks like most of the headers set up by Postman itself are created after the `Pre-request Script`s ran.

This is the script I ended up using:

```
let with_auth = [
    "me",
    "orders"
]
if (with_auth.includes(pm.request.url.path[0])) {
    pm.request.headers.add({
        key: "Authorization",
        value: "Bearer " + pm.variables.get("jwt")
    })
}
```

I use an array to keep track of which endpoints need to have the header set and a variable to store, in my case, the JWT.